# Read text last 7 days

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read several text files which have text with date and success.
The Idea is to read logs from the last 7 days which are continuously a success.

**Example of logs:**

```
12/5/2018 3:40:08 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6335
12/6/2018 3:40:06 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6337
12/7/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6338
12/8/2018 3:40:09 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/9/2018 3:40:09 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/10/2018 3:40:11 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/11/2018 3:40:07 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/12/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6344
12/13/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6347
```

**Log type 2:**

```
12/6/2018 3:40:06 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6337
12/7/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6338
12/8/2018 3:40:09 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/9/2018 3:40:09 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/10/2018 3:40:11 AM: Something_secret.txt file Not found
12/11/2018 3:40:07 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6342
12/12/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6344
12/13/2018 3:40:10 AM: Something_secret.txt file Not found
```

I have created this

```
$files = gci C:\Users\Desktop\xx
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)-f 'MM/d/yyyy'
    $today = ((Get-Date -Format MM/d/yyyy))
    gc $file.FullName | where {
        $_ -match $date -and
        $_ -match $today -match 'Successfully'
    } | select @{n='Pathoffile';e={$file.FullName}}
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your current code is not doing, let me know...

Comment: Its trying to read dates starting from last 7 days till today and also find a pattern successfully so that I can figure out which files are success since last 7 days

Comment: Personally i've never had the greatest luck with the `-match` parameter. Have you try using a different parameter that might return the same results? Like `-Like` or `-Contains`

Comment: I don't think that is going to work my idea script should last 7 days if it contains all string successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ansgar's idea of the last seven entries all containing the string `successfully` but using the `-Tail` parameter of `Get-Content.`

```
$files = gci .\*.log # C:\Users\Desktop\xx

$CkeckSuccess7 = foreach ($file in $files) {
    if (7 -eq (gc $file.FullName -Tail 7 | where {$_ -match 'Successfully'}).Count){
        $Result = $True 
    } else { 
        $Result = $False
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Pathoffile=$file.FullName
        Success7=$Result
    }
}
$CkeckSuccess7
```

---

```
Pathoffile                    Success7
----------                    --------
Q:\Test\2018\12\13\fail.log      False
Q:\Test\2018\12\13\succes.log     True
```

Comment: aha these seems to work I created test files in test server, let me try in my real environment

Comment: Yould could put that also in an `} else { $Result = $False }` clause of the `if`

Comment: I did `if($Result -eq 'True'){'Sucessfull uploads in last 7 days'} else{'Failures in last 7 days'}` and $result=$null still its included :P

Comment: Compare to `$True` --> `if($Result -eq $True){'Sucessfull uploads in last 7 days'} else {'Failures in last 7 days'}`

Comment: Any idea to exclude failures? I tried this no luck `Result2=if($result -eq 'false'){'Failures in last 7 days'}else{}
        Result=if($Result -eq 'True'){'Sucessfull uploads in last 7 days'} 
        
    }
}
$CkeckSuccess7|select pathoffile,clientname,result|fl`

Comment: There are several ways, move the [PSCustomObject into the `if (...){here}` or on the final output append `$CkeckSuccess7 | Where-Object Success7 -eq $True`

Comment: you can edit the answer with that, might help someone as well as me, I really appreciate BDW I'm gonna implement this now on live

Answer (score 0):

simplest i could made:

```
$last7day = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-7)
#get content from file just provide path ( you can do it in loop)
$files = Get-Content -Path ...
#a line example
$files = '12/12/2018 3:40:08 AM: Something_secret.txt Successfully 6335'

foreach ($line in $files){

    [datetime]$date = $line  -replace "[^:]:.*",''

    if ($date -gt $last7day ) {$line}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your logs seem to only have one record per day, the simplest approach would be to select the last seven lines from each file and check if all of them contain the word "Successfully". One way of doing that is by checking if at least one of the lines doesn't contain the word, and then negating that condition.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Desktop\xx | Where-Object {
    -not (Get-Content $_.FullName |
        Select-Object -Last 7 |
        Where-Object {$_ -notlike '*Successfully*'})
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Comment: wow it was so simple and effective :P let me update you guys thanks a ton

Comment: @Jondrew I have no idea what you mean by "not work in real time", but if it doesn't work you either did something different from what I suggested, or have some additional requirement that you didn't specify in your question.